# C++: A way to find what is dependant on Visual C++ Redistribute

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, redistributable

I did lots of stuff with my training project in C++ for which stackoverflow helped me a lot. I always tried to keep it as much "standard" as possible so it would be cross-platform. Using boost here and there, the C++11 threading and a wrapper which uses either the WIN32 sockets or the BSD API. And I decided to compile to RELEASE for a friend just to show off and it required MSVCPP110.dll installed on his computer :(

I had that problem in early beginning but then I set the Visual Studio to compile the MFC as a STATIC library, and that fixed the initial tests, but I have no idea what is it I've put into the code that would require "my users" to install Visual C++ Redistribute for a simple console application that starts 2 threads and opens a TCP socket on one of them.

Do you have any tips to a newbie, how can I check what is it that bothers my system, OR a way to include it with the executable file, I've seen some games on my computer have the aforementioned DLL in their install directories, would it work if I just package that DLL with my executable?

Thanks for any suggestion on this matter in advance!

PS: After thorough review of my code I realized that this might be a problem

`#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")`

But I don't seem to find a static version of this library :U Is there any workaround to that. I need that library for the WSA startup call

`WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &Winsock);`

Comment: ws2_32.lib is a part of Windows, not Visual Studio. Don't distribute it. VC++ comes with an exhaustive list what you *may* redistribute.

Answer (score 4):

you don't need ALL the files usually just 1 or two
like mfcXXX and msvcrxxx

check your dependencies using http://dependencywalker.com/ and add those to your distrubution